# while traversing through results in laravel in foreach loop it saves only last element in new array element?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**My Controller**

$followers = Followers::where('requested', $user->id)->where('status', 1)->get();

```
    foreach ($followers as $follower){

        $followerss = User::with('id', $follower->requester)->get();

    }
```

if I had two or more followers for that particular id, but im $followerss variable it stores only the last follower data but not previous data.

Thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are overwriting the value of variable `$followerss` with each iteration.

You need to declare `$followerss` as an array before it enters the loop, then in the loop `merge` or `push` the items

Push example:

```
$followerss = [];

foreach ($followers as $follower){

    $users = User::with('id', $follower->requester)->get();
    foreach($users as $user) {
        $followerss[] = $user;
    }

}
```

Merge example:

```
$followerss = [];

foreach ($followers as $follower){

    $followerss = array_merge($followerss, User::with('id', $follower->requester)->get());

}
```